# Could not find stored procedure - SQLDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Other similar questions haven't really been relevant to my problem so I'm making a new one...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2"  runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CatalogosConnectionString %>" 
                          InsertCommand="dbo.GRM_Novo_Catalogo" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"> 
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Nome" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="NomeAbreviado" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Estado" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrganismoID" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TipoCatalogoID" Type="Int64" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["Nome"].DefaultValue = TextBox13.Text;
    SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["NomeAbreviado"].DefaultValue = TextBox14.Text;
    SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["Estado"].DefaultValue = TextBox15.Text;
    SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["OrganismoID"].DefaultValue = TextBox16.Text;
    SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["TipoCatalogoID"].DefaultValue = TextBox17.Text;
    SqlDataSource2.Insert();
}
```

So What I want is that when the user clicks on Button2 it runs that stored procedure from the Database, however when testing it brings up an error message saying it could not find the stored procedure.

I am using the same connection string on another SQLDataSource and it works (this also uses a stored procedure which is in the same place as the one in the code above)

Stack trace:

```
Message:
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.GRM_Novo_Catalogo'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.GRM_Novo_Catalogo'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.Insert()
   at EmptyWebsite3.Modules.DNNModule1.Edit.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\me\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite3\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\Edit.ascx.cs:line 79
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: may be you have typo here ? GRM_Novo_Catalogo or GRM_Novo_Cataloge? :)

Comment: As correctly ArsenMkrt pointed out, take a carefully look at the name of your stored procedure. It's quite possible that there is the problem.

Comment: I copy and pasted the name, it's all correctly spelled. I'm portuguese that's why it's written like so.

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: Posted stack trace, also like I mentioned above, I'm using the same connection string for another SqlDataSource (which also uses a stored procedure) and it is working fine

Comment: What happens if you remove 'dbo.' from the beginning of the stored procedure? What happens if you execute the stored procedure directly in the database?

Comment: Does the stored procedure have permission to be executed by the call you are making to it?

Comment: You don't need dbo there in stored procedure name. See following link.http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/ADO.net-Database/SqlDataSourceUpdateStoredProcedure.htm

Comment: Removing the .dbo doesn't fix it. @MartinSmellworse I doesn't seem to be a problem with permissions

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Executing stored procedure directly in the database works perfectly.

Comment: At which point I would be making a copy of the stored procedure, calling it 'fred' and calling that to see if that, also, is not found. If you open SQL Server Management Studio, the procedure is definitely there? In the right database?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse It is for sure in the right place, I was going to post a screenshot of it but I need to have a rep of 10. I created the same stored procedure except with the name "fred" as you said and I get the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the procedure to the one you say already works - so, presumably, you would be passing the wrong parameters to it - does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is grasping at straws - have you tried different syntax for calling your SP?

Here is a typical call that I use in a DataAccess class:

```
public int setUserTimescale(DataObjects.UserDetails myUserDetails)
{
    int ReturnValue = -1;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = "User_Timescale_Up";
    myCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myUserDetails.UserID;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("TimescaleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myUserDetails.TimescaleID;

    SqlParameter parameterReturnValue = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
    parameterReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterReturnValue);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Get the return value
        ReturnValue = (int)myCommand.Parameters[2].Value;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        setDBError(myCommand, e.Message.ToString(), "User_Timescale_Up");
        ReturnValue = -2;
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}
```